# How to sum two values from different rows and get the combination of values that are close to a certain value?

Tags: excel, vba

The sum should be of one value from row 1 and another value from column 1. Need list of combinations that have the sum close to 1309. 
[Row 1 Values] = [720,830,924,1192,1208,1232,1493,1908,2086, 2361]
[Column 1 Values] = [85.5,108.8,136.7,169.5,207.3,251.3,301.7,359.2,424.4,497.9,579.7]

```vb
Sub ExtractValues()

    Dim iLowVal As Integer
    Dim iHighVal As Integer

    iLowVal = InputBox("Lowest value wanted?")
    iHighVal = InputBox("Highest value wanted?")

    For Each cell In Range("A16:A26", "C15:L15")
        If cell.Total <= iHighVal And cell.Value >= iLowVal Then
            ActiveCell.Value = cell.Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share your data and your desired results. It's impossible to reverse engineer your non-working code with only a pretty vague sentence. For instance: What is a "Specified Row" and what is a "Different Row"? How do you get a single value from a "Row" with many cells? Please also explain the logic on how you get from your sample data to your desired results so it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do here, (or why) but I'll take a crack at it.

To start with you need to declare cell, though cell already has a meaning so I would change that name, or load the two ranges into arrays.

```
Dim targetrow() as variant 
dim targetcol() as variant
```

`cell.total` is not a thing, you probably meant `cell.value`.

If you want to add one element from the row and one from the column your current code isn't going to do that. It is just cycling though all the cells in your range and comparing the value to `ihighval` and `ilowval`.

These next two lines are not doing much, your active cell would be whatever you clicked on, then you are activating the one below it. If you want to create a new column of data, specifying the range would be better. Since your data is in a table-like format I'll just put them at the intersection of the respective row and column.

```
ActiveCell.Value = cell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
```

```
Sub ExtractValues()

    dim iLowVal as integer
    dim iHighVal as integer
    dim TargetRow() as variant
    dim TargetCol() as variant
    dim RowElem as variant
    dim ColElem as variant
    dim CurrentRow as integer
    dim CurrentCol as integer    


    iLowVal = InputBox("Lowest value wanted?")
    iHighVal = InputBox("Highest value wanted?")

    TargetRow = Range("A16:A26").value
    TargetCol = Range("C15:L15").value

    CurrentRow = 16

    for each RowElem in TargetRow
        if RowElem >= iLowVal and RowElem <= iHighVal then
            CurrentCol = 3
            for each ColElem in TargetCol
               if ColElem >= iLowVal and ColElem <= iHighVal then
                   cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).value = RowElem + ColElem
               end if
               CurrentCol = CurrentCol + 1
            Next
         end if
         CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
     Next
End Sub
```

I didn't do anything with the sum close to 1309 because I don't know what you are getting at there. If you want it to be within fifty or something like that then you would you just need a similar check on the value like you do for the low val and high val. If the low val and high val are meant to be applied to the sum and not the elements you just need to move the conditional.